# The Angular session is killed after the putty session timeout

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, angular-cli

I just want to run the Angular to run forever until I kill it manual So I just used the below command to run it as service in linux box

```
 nohup ng serve --host {xyz.com} &
```

It will make the application Up and running and created nohup.out file but the session is gone as soon as the putty is time out.

Can anyone lead me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be good idea to use production ready tools like systemd to run your nodejs applicaiton - this manual can help:

https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/

In your case, if your ng app is saved in `/opt/app` directory, unit file will be something like this

```
[Unit]
Description=hello_env.js - making your environment variables rad
Documentation=https://example.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3001
Type=simple
User=ubuntu

Workdir=/opt/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/app/.bin/ng serve --host {xyz.com}

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in 2nd part (https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-2/), they explained how to start few instances of application and use nginx in front of them as load balancer and reverse proxy with HTTPS support

Comment: Security issue !! ng serve is running a simple http server not secured !!!

Comment: if you read further, you'll find how they used nginx as load balancer and reverse proxy with HTTPS enabled, so i think your comment is unrelated

Comment: It helped my a lot. Thank you. I will also look into that How to enable HTTPS protocol. Upvoted and accepted answer. Once again thanks for timely response.

Comment: **I said it once, but I will repeat myself, you shouldn't use ng serve for production !!!**

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using ng serve in production, what you need to do is build your Angular App and use something like `proxy_pass` in a real server (like nginx or apache) to tell it to serve your Angular static app files (index.html + js bundles)

**You are taking a big risk by running the app with `ng serve` on a server as the http server behind it is not secure !**

Comment: We implemented the SSO layer before proceed to use the application. Can you please help me how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: SSO has nothing to do with this, first result for deploy angular nginx on google: https://www.stackextend.com/angular/deploy-angular-app-using-nginx/